# Mongoose.js and the query object with Regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In a locomotive app, in a search engine that queries my models (with rather specific metadata that I won't go into here for the usual reasons)  I need to include a regexp engine to check against the keywords field.

My approach  is as follows:

```
this.keywords = strings.makeSafe(this.param("keywords")).toLowerCase();
console.log(this.keywords);
if(strings.exists(this.keywords)) {
    keywords = this.keywords.split(", ");
    var len = keywords.length - 1; 
    do { 
        query.regex("/" + this.keywords[len] + "/ig", "keywords");
    } while(len--);
}
```

(It's this.keywords so that I can pass it to the view should I need to).

however, I'm not matching data that I know to be available in the documents in the collection

the `strings.makesafe` call simply does this:

```
strings.makeSafe = function(str) {
  str = String(str);
  var re = /\$/gi;
  str =  str.replace(re, "U+FF04");
  re = /\./gi;
  return str.replace(re, "U+FF08"); 
};
```

and is an attempt to deal with mongoose's vulnerability to code injection via the "." and "$" characters.  It's been tested and shouldn't be driving the issue.

I'm of the mind right now that it's something to do with the structure of the regexp or the calling method.  is this the correct syntax to accomplish a search on comma separated list of keywords in mongoose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your approach:

1. Assuming that `query` is a Mongoose `Query` object, you've got the order swapped for the parameters to the [`regex`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-regex) method as the path comes first, then the regex value.
2. You need to construct the regular expression using the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor function as the literal notation with the `/` chars can't be dynamically constructed from strings.
3. Calling `query.regex` in a loop like that doesn't OR the conditions together as each call simply overwrites the previous one.  Instead, you can join the keywords together into a combined regex that matches any of them by using `|`.

Putting it all together it should be something like:

```
this.keywords = strings.makeSafe(this.param("keywords")).toLowerCase();
console.log(this.keywords);
if (strings.exists(this.keywords)) {
    keywords = this.keywords.split(", ");
    query.regex("keywords", new RegExp(keywords.join("|"), "i"));
}
```

Comment: This looks really good and is a great explanation of the gaps.  I haven't had a chance to test yet, but as soon as I do I'll reward the points.